# Check if keys are toggled

Tags: c#, input, xna, sprite

How would you see if a key has been released?

I want for example, when the user released the <kbd>Left</kbd> key, the animation of the character stops and stays on the frame where he is looking/facing left

Here is my player class:

```
public class Player
{
    #region Animation
    int currentFrame;
    int frameWidth;
    int frameHeight;

    float timer;
    float interval = 65;
    #endregion

    private Texture2D texture;
    private Vector2 position = new Vector2(64, 200);
    private Vector2 velocity;
    private Rectangle rectangle;
    private bool isMoving;

    KeyboardState keyState;

    public enum playerStates
    {
        RIGHT,
        LEFT,
        WALKINGRIGHT,
        WALKINGLEFT
    }

    playerStates currentPlayerState = playerStates.LEFT;

    private bool hasJumped = false;

    public Vector2 Position
    {
        get { return position; }
    }

    public Player(Texture2D newTexture, Vector2 newPosition, int newFrameWidth, int newFrameHeight)
    {
        texture = newTexture;
        position = newPosition;
        frameWidth = newFrameWidth;
        frameHeight = newFrameHeight;

        isMoving = false;
    }

    public void LoadContent(ContentManager Content)
    {
        texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Mario/full");
    }

    public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        rectangle = new Rectangle(currentFrame * frameWidth, 0, frameWidth, frameHeight);
        position = position + velocity;

        #region Key Presses

        KeyboardState lastKeyState = keyState;

        keyState = Keyboard.GetState();

        if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left))
        {
            //position.X -= 1;
            AnimateLeft(gameTime);
            currentPlayerState = playerStates.LEFT;
            isMoving = true;
        }

        if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right))
        {
            //position.X -= 1;
            AnimateRight(gameTime);
            currentPlayerState = playerStates.RIGHT;
            isMoving = true;
        }


        //Check for last keypresses

        #endregion
    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(texture, position, rectangle, Color.White, 0f, Vector2.Zero, 1.0f, SpriteEffects.None, 1);
    }

    #region DrawAnimation

    public void AnimateLeft(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        timer += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds / 2;
        if (timer > interval)
        {
            currentFrame++;
            timer = 0;
            if (currentFrame > 3 || currentFrame < 2)
            {
                currentFrame = 2;
            }
        }
    }

    public void AnimateRight(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        timer += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds / 2;
        if (timer > interval)
        {
            currentFrame++;
            timer = 0;
            if (currentFrame > 5 || currentFrame < 3)
            {
                currentFrame = 4;
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check if a key is "toggled" or pressed, you need to use two `KeyboardStates`, one for the current frame, and one for the last frame. Looks like you already had some of this going on, but I will just start here

```
public static KeyboardState CurrentKeyboardState;
public static KeyboardState LastKeyboardState;
```

In your update method, you need to set these

```
LastKeyboardState = CurrentKeyboardState;
CurrentKeyboardState = Keyboard.GetState();
```

For checking if a key was pressed, it must be down one frame, and up the other. So we can check with that.

```
if (LastKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left) && !CurrentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left))
     //Do Stuff
```

You can do what I have done, and make a handy extension method so you can simply do `if (Keys.Left.IsKeyToggled)`. If you haven't used [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx) before, you can read about them [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/extension). You will need a static class

```
  public static class Extensions
  {
  }
```

And just use a method which has the code we used above, Replace "Class" with whatever class has the keyboard states.

```
   public static bool IsKeyToggled(this Keys key)
   {
        return Class.LastKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(key) && !Class.CurrentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(key)
   }
```

Comment: Okay, so i added what you wrote to my code:
`` public static class Extensions
        {
            public static bool IsKeyToggled(this Keys key)
             {
                 return !Player.lastKeyState.IsKeyDown(key) && Player.currentKeyState.IsKeyDown(key);
             }
        }``
But i'm not quite sure how to use it :/

Comment: No problem, sorry I couldn't reply, my notifier thing didn't update o_O

Comment: np :) i did:
`` if (!currentKeyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left) && lastKeyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left))
            {
                currentFrame = 3;
            }``

Comment: Also, if you are confused on the extension method, you can just remove the `this` and throw it into your Game/Player class or something, and use it as a normal method `public static bool IsKeyToggled(Keys key)
   {
        return LastKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(key) && !CurrentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(key)
   }` and call `if (IsKeyToggled(Keys.Left))` And sorry about that error, in the code, I corrected it.

Comment: Yeah and another thing, i have a 64x64 mario sprite, is it possible to use a Matrix camera to zoom in without the image getting all blurry? :o

Comment: What do you mean exactly, it has to get blurry when it is zoomed out. Unless what you mean is to make for example, a 64x64 sprite with 1x1 pixels, into a 128x128 pixel sprite with 2x2 pixels, that is possible

Comment: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/6822/13911 Is basically what I was going to say.

Comment: yeah got that part up and running :) now i just gotta find a way to make my camera fixed to the player..cus im using this : transform = Matrix.CreateScale(new Vector3(1, 1, 0)) *
                Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(-center.X, -center.Y, 0)); And when i increase the "CreateScale", and move the character, it eventually gets off-screen.. :/

Comment: I'd do something like: `Matrix cameraTransform = Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(-Player.Position, 0f));` and `spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred, BlendState.AlphaBlend, SamplerState.PointClamp, DepthStencilState.Default, RasterizerState.CullCounterClockwise, null, cameraTransform);` (See `CameraTransform` at the end